# I want Camera.main to follow the player, it works fine in Editor, but not on Android Deice

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 3d

Could you please help me in the following matter:

In Unity3D I want Camera.main to follow the player, it works fine in Editor, but not on Android Device

Could you help me, please
Andy

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information in here. Particularly around how you are setting your camera to follow the player. Where does it work? Are you sure that you are running the right scene when you build to Android? Have you successfully built a desktop version of the game and saw the camera follow or is it only following in the editor? Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks a lot for replying,

Comment: 1) I've got only onse scene in my project        2) I use usual methods: Camera.main.transform.rotation = go.transform.rotation;
                Camera.main.transform.position = go.transform.position;  3) I use camera transform in Update     4) Yes, I've just tried - standalone version on my Win 10 works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the Android Logcat, you can find package in Window -> PackageManager menu. Install it, then build-and-run your game on android device, connected via usb cable. 
Probably, you trying to do something platform dependant, which gives you an error on android. And this error blocks your code from further execution.
Also you can try not to use Camera.main, but use direct camera reference instead, like

```
public Camera myCamera;
void Update()
{
myCamera.transform.position = transform.position - myCamera.transform.forward * 10;
}
```

Did you used any ads/services plugins?
Any camera plugins, like AR or video chat?
Do you use additive scene loading?
Can you show your code? How exactly camera follow implemented?